# Gitlab: Working with multiple Users

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

I have created a gitlab repo and also have set up SSH keys. I can push my changes to the repo. When another developer wants to contribute to the same repo (project), how can I set up Gitlab so that he can also work with the repository. I would be glad if someone can give me instructions as to how to do that as steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is going to need to setup his own SSH key or you will need to give him one of the private keys if that's the route you want to go...

Otherwise, you could just invite him to edit the repo (assuming he has an account). To navigate to those settings go to your desired project repository in your web browser, and find the "Settings" menu on the left side. Inside there, you will see "Members". There you can enter the developer's credentials to allow him access to the repo.